# How can I generate the Numeric Keyboard using kivy and kivyMD?

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How can I display a numeric keyboard using Kivy==2.0.0 and kivyMD? I set `input_type:'number'`, `input_filter:'int'` and `multiline:False` in textfield but when I run apk on android device app display only full character keyboard.
Better mention that buildozer couldn't download sdl2 files and I manually replaced sdl2 files.

python version = 3.8.5

buildozer = Latest version

sdl2 version = 2.0.9

Answer (score 1):

After much effort I realized that numeric keyboard works only with `kivy==master` and `p4a==develop`.
So I changed `buildozer.spec` requirements from `kivy==2.0.0` to `kivy==master`,also p4a.branch from master to develop.Now numeric keyboard works fine.

Comment: follow up to this. when my first text field shows a numeric keypad, for some reason, my other textfield bring up a numeric keypad even if i didn't set it that way